# powershell IE automation getElementByID with multiple entries

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell, automation

this only gets the first of the elements, though the backend cgi (such as php) can get all these in an array.

```
$surl=some url
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($surl)
$doc = $ie.Document
$element = $doc.getElementByID("some_name[]")
```

this only gets the first of the elements with the same name.

i am trying to fill values with a script but so far have not figured out a way to go beyond the first of these elements. i do not control the document rendering so cannot change how these are named.

thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTML ID has to be unique! So that's why you only get one.

From: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).
>
> The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet,
>   and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with
>   the specific id.

Per the [getElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of
>   the ID or NAME attribute.

Use [getElementsByClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [getElementsByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [getElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.