# debugging powershell login webpage script

Tags: powershell

I have this poweshell script  - which opens up the webpage - however the idea is that it would log into the page. It pulls up the page ok, but does not put anything in the login/password box. I got the getelementbyid'd from google chrome tools.

Do you have any idea on how to troubleshoot this script. Like in perl or bash I can put in echo statements.  i can use set -x to check the output. I want to see it the script is entering in the login and password.

```
param
         (
           [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
           [ValidateNotNull()]
           $ID
         )


$username = "casper"
$password = "passworD"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$false
$ie.navigate("http://casperweb.stm.swissbank.com:8080/cds/marketAccessAcctLimits.jsp?Term=$ID")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 1}
$ie.Document.getElementById("userName").value= "$username"
$ie.Document.getElementById("password").value = "$password"
$ie.Document.getElementById("submitButton").Click()
start-sleep 20
$ie.Document.body | Out-File -FilePath c:\UBS\DEV\web.txt
```

Comment: Did you try making the window visible to check if the fields are filled up ? It worked when I tried on Google. What do you mean, you cannot differenciate the body of a logged on user from the body of a non logged on user ? Does the content change if you enter bad credentials or no credentials at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a specific error message? Without being able to access your page it's difficult to determine if the element id is correct. Your code and post prompted me to try something similar and I only saw the issue you described when I wasn't entering the correct element id of the fields I was trying to populate.

I found the below articles helpful for inspecting the element and getting the correct ID.

http://kb.oboxthemes.com/articles/how-to-get-css-styles-for-elements/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435732/5587481

I'm not an expert at this in any way so hopefully I understand the issue at hand correctly here :)